# Find the area of the region inside the inner loop of the​ limaçon

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area of the region inside the inner loop of the​ limaçon $r=7+14\cos(\theta)$

[image]

[image]

So doing this problem, I got B the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$: $\dfrac{1}{2}  (7+14\cos(\theta))^2$  and the area as $98\pi$. Is the correct way and correct answer? I will also upload my work to get $98\pi$. Thanks for any feedback and help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a polar plot of the function $r(\theta) =7+14 \cos \theta$ for $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$.

Note that the curve passes through the origin when $r(\theta) = 0$.
Solving this for $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$ gives solutions $\pi \pm { \pi \over 3}$.

[image]

Hence you need to compute $A = {1 \over 2}\int_{2 \pi \over 3}^{4 \pi \over 3} r^2(\theta) d \theta$.

Scroll over for answer:

> Computing gives $A = {7^2 \over 2} (2 \pi -3 \sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The inner loop corresponds to the interval $[\theta_0,\theta_1]\subset[0,2\pi]\;$ such that $\;r(\theta_0)=r(\theta_1)=0$.